# How can an exception written in same class library for console, windows and web with C#?

Tags: c#, windows, exception, console, class-library

I am trying to create a class library in C#. Once an exception occured, I want to show an exception message to user. However this library may be used in a console or windows form both. When the application is running, how can I know the running environment and show a message?

```
// Some codes

try
{
    // Successful codes
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var App; // How can we find current application environment?

    if (App == console_app)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
    }
    else if (App == windows_form) // OR wpf
    {
        MessageBox.Show (ex.Message, "Exception Message");
    }
    else if (App == web_app) // asp.net mvc
    {
        // an error page OR javascript message
    }

    throw;
}

// Other codes
```

Comment: if you are providing the exception to whom may use your library, you should just throw the exception, and they should handle it.

Comment: Well, it's not the library job to show the exception message to the user, but the application's. What the class should do is throw an exception and let the application deal with it.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider your advises.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I know the running environment and show a message

There are ways but why do you care? if at all you want to show a different message to user, you can define a `const` like `private const string app = "web"` and use that in your catch block. rest all will remain same, refer the class library dll which defines the exception and use the exception type in your `catch` block

Comment: Thanks. I will consider your advises.